# Laravel 6.x: Adding blank row when importing in maatwebsite excel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Recently, we upgraded the laravel version from 5.x to 6.1 because of this our code in maatwebsite has been deprecated so now we need to update our code.

```
laravel version 6.20
php version 7.4.9
maatwebsite 3.1
```

Now Im upgrading the code of maatwebsite in importing but having an issue "Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value" even though the variable has a value.

This error occur because it is creating a blank data when I import

Note: We are using query builder not eloquent model.

I already added the *WithHeadingRow*, *SkipsEmptyRows* in my class but it is still creating a blank data

**Controller**

```
class ChartOfAccountImportCSVController implements ToModel, WithValidation, SkipsEmptyRows, WithHeadingRow, SkipsOnFailure, WithMapping
{

public function model(array $row)
{
        $chart_of_account_type                = GlobalModel::getSingleDataTableByNameWithoutCompanyNotLike('chart_of_account_types',$row['chart_of_account_type']);
        // app(\App\Http\Livewire\Others\AuditTrail\AuditTrailIndex::class)->saveAuditTrail($row['code'],7,"Imported");
        
        $result = ChartOfAccount::test('chart_of_accounts',[
            'chart_of_account_type_id'              => $chart_of_account_type->id,
            'code'                                  => $row['account_code'],
            'orig_code'                             => $row['account_code'],
            'name'                                  => $row['account_name'],
            'description'                           => $row['description'],
            'company_id'                            => Auth::user()->company_id,
            'created_by'                            => Auth::user()->id,
            'created_at'                            => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'status'                                => '1'
        ]);
        // $data['function_name']  = 'Chart Of Accounts';
        // $data['number']         = $row['account_code'];
        //audit trail function
        // trailCreate($data);
       return new $result;
 }
}
```

**Model**

```
public static function test($table,$data)
{
            DB::table($table)
                ->insert($data);
        $result = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        
        return \App\ChartOfAccount::query()
                ->where('id',$result)
                ->first();

 }
```

Question: Why does it create a blank row?

[image]